# How to do google login authorization with tornado 3.2.2 using GoogleOAuth2Mixin

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, tornado, google-oauth

I am trying to implement Google Oauth 2.0 login for my tornado app. They have made some changes with 3.2.2 and they do not seem to have clear instructions. Following is my code:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get_current_user(self):
        user = self.get_secure_cookie('trakr')
        if not user: return None
        return True

class ProductsHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        self.render("products.html")
        return

class GAuthLoginHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.GoogleOAuth2Mixin):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        if self.get_current_user():
            self.redirect('/products')
            return

        if self.get_argument('code', False):
            user = yield self.get_authenticated_user(redirect_uri=settings.google_redirect_url,
                code=self.get_argument('code'))
            if not user:
                self.clear_all_cookies() 
                raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, 'Google authentication failed')

            access_token = str(user['access_token'])
            http_client = self.get_auth_http_client()
            http_client.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token='+access_token, self._save_user_profile)
            return

        elif self.get_secure_cookie('trakr'):
            self.redirect('/products')
            return

        else:
            yield self.authorize_redirect(
                redirect_uri=settings.google_redirect_url,
                client_id=self.settings['google_oauth']['key'],
                scope=['email'],
                response_type='code',
                extra_params={'approval_prompt': 'auto'})

    def _save_user_profile(self, response):
        if not response:
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, "Google authentication failed.")
        user = json.loads(response.body)
        self.set_secure_cookie('trakr', user['email']) 
        self.redirect('/products')
```

Currently I am getting following error:

```
[E 140702 12:35:30 ioloop:491] Exception in callback <functools.partial object at 0xa51ff54>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 477, in _run_callback
        callback()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 331, in wrapped
        raise_exc_info(exc)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 302, in wrapped
        ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "main.py", line 202, in _save_user_profile
        self.redirect('/')
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 629, in redirect
        raise Exception("Cannot redirect after headers have been written")
    Exception: Cannot redirect after headers have been written
```

I don't understand where I am setting the response headers.

- How to fix this issue?
- I am doing this right way? Do you have any example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix coroutine and callback styles.  The `http_client.fetch` call at the end of the `if self.get_argument('code')` block should use a yield and no callback argument (and then inline the `_save_user_profile` method before the return)

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is looking, here is the script after Ben's answer:

```
class GAuthLoginHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.GoogleOAuth2Mixin):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        if self.get_current_user():
            self.redirect('/products')
            return

        if self.get_argument('code', False):
            user = yield self.get_authenticated_user(redirect_uri=settings.google_redirect_url,
                code=self.get_argument('code'))
            if not user:
                self.clear_all_cookies() 
                raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, 'Google authentication failed')

            access_token = str(user['access_token'])
            http_client = self.get_auth_http_client()
            response =  yield http_client.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token='+access_token)
            if not response:
                self.clear_all_cookies() 
                raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, 'Google authentication failed')
            user = json.loads(response.body)
            # save user here, save to cookie or database
            self.set_secure_cookie('trakr', user['email']) 
            self.redirect('/products')
            return

        elif self.get_secure_cookie('trakr'):
            self.redirect('/products')
            return

        else:
            yield self.authorize_redirect(
                redirect_uri=settings.google_redirect_url,
                client_id=self.settings['google_oauth']['key'],
                scope=['email'],
                response_type='code',
                extra_params={'approval_prompt': 'auto'})
```